# Confused by Question on new A Level Maths Sample Paper

Tags: trigonometry

Visit: https://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/A%20Level/Mathematics/2017/specification-and-sample-assesment/a-level-l3-mathematics-sams.pdf

Q $13$(a) for the Pure Maths Paper is on parametric differentiation. I got $2\sqrt{3}\cos (t)$ for the top of the fraction, as $\sqrt{3}\sin 2(t)$ is the same as $\sqrt{3}(2\sin (t)\cos (t))$ and $\sin (t)$ is cancelled by $\sin(t)$ on the bottom.

However, for the denominator I got $2\sin (t)$, rather than $\sin (t)$. Am I missing something here, or have the exam board got it wrong?

Comment: The derivative of $y = \sqrt3 \cos 2t$ is $y' = -2\sqrt3 \sin 2t = -4\sqrt3 \sin t \cos t$.  Don't forget the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the question you are asking about!

The curve $C$ has parametric equations $x = 2 \cos t$, $y = \sqrt{3} \cos 2t$, $0 \leq t \leq \pi$. Find an expression for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$.

The solution to the question is as follows:-

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ $$\therefore \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\frac{d}{dt} \left( \sqrt{3} \cos 2t \right)}{\frac{d}{dt} \left( 2 \cos t \right)}$$ $$\therefore \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{- 2 \sqrt{3} \sin 2t}{- 2 \sin t}$$ $$\therefore \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{4 \sqrt{3} \sin t \cos t}{2 \sin t}$$ $$\therefore \dfrac{dy}{dx} =  2 \sqrt{3} \cos t$$